# How to await a list of ListenableFuture with a timeout

Tags: java, guava, future

I'm working on a problem where I have a `List<ListenableFuture<T>>`. I would like to aggregate the results of all of these futures into a `List<T>` with a timeout. The naive approach would be something like:

```
List<T> blockForResponses(List<ListenableFuture<T>> futures, long timeoutMillis) {
    return futures.stream()
        .map(future -> future.get(timeoutMillis,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This doesn't work because it waits for the timeout for *each* future and I want that to be the timeout for the entire list. Manually keeping track of how much time has passed also doesn't work because if the first one times out, there won't be any time left to try the others.

The solution I'm looking for would enforce a timeout on all of the futures and return when the timeout had elapsed or all of the futures in the list were complete. Then I could inspect each future in the list myself to aggregate the results and check which ones timed out.

Comment: `Futures.allAsList(futures).get(timeoutMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`?  Or `successfulAsList`, depending on your intended semantics?

Comment: @Louis won't those result in the future failing if the time out is exceeded? Then I won't be able to get the successful results

Comment: In other words, the `get` call on the `Future` returned by `allAsList` will throw a `TimeoutException`

Comment: I think successfulAsList would work, then

Comment: @Roy I think that will have the same problem. `successfulAsList` returns a `ListenableFuture` which, when `get` is called with a timeout, throws an exception when the timeout expires.

Comment: I believe Daniel is correct.  You might get away with `successfulAsList` after using `withTimeout` on all the futures?

Comment: @Louis but then do I need to spin up a new `Exexcutor` to do this?

Comment: Not necessarily, but you'd need a `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: @Louis I haven't been able to figure out from what's available online. Does the timeout passed in `withTimeout` start when it's called or when `get` is called? If the former, that seems like a good answer that I'd love for you to write-up so I could accept it.

Answer (score 9):

This problem turned out to be simpler than I thought. I was able to use the `Futures.allAsList` method and then catch the `TimeoutException`:

```
List<T> blockForResponses(List<ListenableFuture<T>> futures, long timeoutMillis) {
    ListenableFuture<List<T>> futureOfList = Futures.allAsList(futures);
    List<T> responses;
    try {
        responses = futureOfList.get(timeoutMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        responses = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ListenableFuture<T> future : futures) {
            if (future.isDone()) {
                responses.add(Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(future));
            }
        }
    }
    return responses;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I fiddled around a bit (Haven't used Guava's Listenable interface until this evening) but I think this may work for you:
    package basic;

```
import static com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.catching;
import static com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.successfulAsList;
import static com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.withTimeout;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListeningScheduledExecutorService;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors;

public class FuturesExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ListeningScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = MoreExecutors
                .listeningDecorator(Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(20));
        List<ListenableFuture<Integer>> list = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            list.add(catching(
                    withTimeout(scheduledExecutorService.submit(getCallback(i * 1000, i)), 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                            scheduledExecutorService),
                    TimeoutException.class, exception -> 0, scheduledExecutorService));
        }
        ListenableFuture<List<Integer>> result = successfulAsList(list);
        Optional<Integer> sum = result.get().stream().reduce(Integer::sum);
        System.out.println(sum.orElse(-1));
        scheduledExecutorService.shutdownNow();
    }

    private static Callable<Integer> getCallback(int timeout, int value) {
        return () -> {
            Thread.sleep(timeout);
            return value;
        };
    }
}
```

edit: code is a bit cleaner when using static imports for Futures